# Question was edited beyond recognition, causing my answer to be downvoted - what to do?

Tags: discussion

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010539/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-push-while-adding-a-value-to-an-empty/58010621) with a working (tested) code snippet. However, the OP and others have edited the original question many times, without clarifying that they edited it in the question itself. One edit even copied my answer directly.

Now the question is very different from what it was, and my answer is getting downvoted because it seems like I copied the question, while in reality it was the other way around.

Should I:

- Downvote and/or flag the question?
- Remove my answer (and take small but injust a reputation hit)?
- Keep discussing (I really don't feel like it as it seems to be hopeless)?
- Do something else?

Comment: You may also be interested in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286803/change-to-question-invalidates-my-answer-what-to-do) MSE post about question changes invalidating answers

Comment: A rollback is an option to undo the changes.  But if the edits were substantial and helped the OP getting to the point then that's pretty hard to justify.  They seemed to.  You can't win them all, deleting the post is the pragmatic solution.  Fwiw, "don't mark this as duplicate, please!" is a cue that the user doesn't understand how SO works, significantly increases the odds that you'll waste your free time.

Comment: If it were me, I wouldn't delete the post. I'd add the new information to it as new information is put into the question, but I wouldn't delete it.

Comment: Some people have no shame in taking snippets from answers and updating their question without mentioning where they got it.

Comment: You can also edit the Q to include attribution of the source of OP "most recent code", ie link to your Q

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the *something else* category, you can revert the edits (easier if you have >2K rep, will probably get declined if you don't).

Editing in another unrelated question is not really acceptable behavior. However, it's a common enough occurrence, especially when people are rate limited/question banned.

Reverting an edit like that, however, often starts unpleasant discussions and edit wars. I generally avoid it.

The more practical approach is:

1. Flag/vote to close as *Too broad* since the question is really 2 separate questions and should be narrowed down to a single question
2. Consider deleting your answer (you get the rep back, your answer doesn't fully answer the question)
3. Vote on the question as you see fit

Comment: Thanks, your answer and the link commented by @NickA answer my question. I will consider deleting my answer depending on what happens to the question. I didn't know the rep gets refunded (not that I really care about 4 rep, the situation just seemed a bit injust in case it did get lost). Reverting edits also seems like a good response, I just can't really be bothered with it at the moment tbh. I also voted on the question as I saw fit ;)